# Vim Tabularize multiple lines

Tags: regex, vim, vim-tabular

How do i use Vim Tabularize to align the following text

`text1 text2  temp_line0,
 text1 text2  temp_line1,
 text1 text2  [1:0] temp_line2,
 text1 text2  [15:0] temp_line5,
 text1 text2  temp_line6,
 text1 text2  [1:0] temp_line7,
 text1 text2  temp_line8,
 text1 text2  [23:0]temp_line9`

To something like this ..

`text1 text2        temp_line0,
 text1 text2        temp_line1,
 text1 text2 [1:0]  temp_line2,
 text1 text2 [15:0] temp_line5,
 text1 text2        temp_line6,
 text1 text2 [1:0]  temp_line7,
 text1 text2        temp_line8,
 text1 text2 [23:0] temp_line9`

basically i want to align everything after the "]" in the lines

Comment: You do not have a common separator for all your lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the plugin Tabular available on github :https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular

Nevertheless your text does not have a real separator in each of your line so it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be:

`:%s/\(\%>8c\s\|^.*]\)/\1                /`

followed by:
`:%s/\%>25c\s\+//`